# Rails 3 respond_to json, with custom attributes/methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a rails app I have an action that returns a json representation of a collection of different models. It looks *something* like this:

```
respond_to :json

def index
  @cars = Car.all
  @vans = Van.all
  respond_with({
    :cars => @cars,
    :vans => @vans
  })
end
```

However, I want to customise the attributes and methods that are passed to the json object. A bit like:

```
respond_with({
  :cars => @cars.to_json(:only => [:make, :model], :methods => [:full_name]),
  :vans => @vans
})
```

Doing the above, causes the json representation of the "cars" to be escaped as one big string, like:

```
{
  "cars":"[{\"car\":{\"make\":\"Ford\"  ... etc
  "vans": [{"van":{"make":"Citreon"  ... vans not escaped
}
```

Obviously I'm approaching this the wrong way. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're nesting the `to_json` in another `Hash`, I think you need to use `as_json` (which returns a `Hash` instead of a `String`) instead:

```
respond_with({
  :cars => @cars.as_json(:only => [:make, :model], :methods => [:full_name]),
  :vans => @vans
})
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you. (will accept this answer as soon as I'm allowed)