# Custom model method that should be included in JSON serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, model

I'm working with a javascript library where I build comboboxes.
I have the requirement of build a combobox with **full name** of a person, so I mean name + surname.

Because in database those are 2 separate field (and in my model too), I would like to know if there is a fast way (instead of manually build all hash objects) to "simulate" the presence of an additional field in my model for JSON conversion, because this object must be returned as a JSON array where you can read *full_name* as a key.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can overwrite the to_json method in your model by passing `:methods` options and call `super`. This will call `as_json` version of the super class with `:methods` options so that it will serialize your model with `full_name` attributes.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(options={})
    options[:methods] = [:full_name]
    super
  end

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Inside your controller, you can simply

```
render :json => @person
```

Check this document out if you want to know more options that can pass to `as_json` method.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: Nice answer mate, nice example too. Give me a second to test but I think will work gracefully.

Comment: Obviusly ;) Your answer is correct but I forgot to mention a thing, what if I want to **omit** some fields from json conversion to avoid bandwith consumption?

Comment: You can add the :except option inside the `as_json`. Did you check the link in my answer yet?

Comment: Nope, sorry while answering I'm working on the javascript part of the code, crunch time :(. I'm watching it now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a duplicate of this question:

[Rails 3 respond_to json, with custom attributes/methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509736/rails-3-respond-to-json-with-custom-attributes-methods)

Specifically the :methods hash:

```
respond_with({
  :cars => @cars.as_json(:only => [:make, :model], :methods => [:full_name]),
  :vans => @vans
})
```

Comment: I can't merge the 2 answer but your is useful too. Chamnap is better for my situation but your answer is helpful for situation where you would like to include methods in json conversion "temporary" (because they are passed as an option rather than an override).

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is have a setter method in your User class like so

```
def full_name=(string)
  names = string.split # the default delimiter is a space
  self.update_attributes(:first_name => names[0], :last_name => names[1])
end
```

The form should then refer to `:full_name` as a field, and even though it's not an actual column, Rails will automatically access this method above and execute it, thereby updating the columns you actually want.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant, I need the opposite: reading the full_name and write it in a JSON object, not convert my json object into a rails model object.